# Excel VBA finding an exact string using .Find and .FindNext

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble using .Find and .FindNext.  I want to search for the string "Q1" exactly.  Currently, when my .FindNext function runs, it finds  "Q1" in a cell that has "Q10" as its value.  How do I restrict the .Find and/or .FindNext functions to search for the exact string that I want?
Thank you for your help!

Here is my code. For example, I want to find the third instance of "Q1" in a range of cells that may have Q1, Q3, Q5, Q10, Q11, Q1, Q2, Q1 and so on.

```
Dim findValue As Range

' find first instance of Q1
searchString = "Q1" 
Set findValue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=searchString)
findValue.select

' set loopMax to 2 because we want to .Findnext to run two more times to arrive at the third instance of "Q1" 
For counter = 1 To loopMax
Set findValue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.FindNext(findValue)
findValue.select
Next counter
```

I am stuck. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Need to add `lookat:=xlWhole` in your call to `Find()`

Comment: Dude, Thanks!! You guys are life savers.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `lookat:=xlWhole` in your call to Find()